# DroidCam error while loading shared libraries

Tags: shared-library, droidcam

I have installed Droidcam On Xubuntu 20.04 LTS  with [this great tutorial](https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linux/).

After running Droidcam in terminal, I came across this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libappindicator3.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I searched `libappindicator`:

```
sudo apt search libappindicator
```

I just picked the most recent version and the error is gone:

```
sudo apt search libappindicator3-1
```